# Likelihood function is joint measurable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Here is the problem in Theory of Statistics Schervish:

> Let $\Theta$ be a parameter with parameter space $(\Omega, \tau)$ ($\tau$ is the $\sigma$ algebra). Let $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta) = dP_\theta/d\nu$ for every $\theta$. Let $\mu_\Theta$ be a prior on $(\Omega, \tau)$. Let $Q$ be the joint distribution of $(X,\Theta)$. Show that $f_{X|\Theta}= dQ/(d\nu\times \mu_\Theta)$, a.s. $\nu\times \mu_\Theta$. This means for every prior distribution, we can find a version of $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)$ which is joint measurable $(x,\theta)$.

Let $A\in \mathcal{F}$, $B\in \tau$.
\begin{align}
Q(A\times B) = \int_{B}\int_{A}f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)\ d\nu d\mu_\Theta
\end{align}
The RHS can be extended uniquely to a measure on $(X,\Omega)$, so it is equal to $Q$. However, I am having trouble proving $Q<< \nu\times \mu_\Theta$. If $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)\in L^1$ then we can conclude this immediately. However, in this case $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)$ is not even joint measurable, we cannot use Tonelli's Theorem to rewrite the iterated integral. Does anyone know how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are saying, that you are having trouble proving, that $Q << \nu \otimes \mu_\Theta$, but it would seem that you already have. Remember by definition of absolute continuity, that  $Q << \nu \otimes \mu_\Theta$ if and only if
$$\forall C \in \mathcal{F}\otimes \tau \: : \: \Big(\nu\otimes\mu_\Theta(C)=0 \Rightarrow Q(C) = 0\Big),$$
but you have already proven this for the special case $C=A\times B$ and it can easily be extended to all $C$ (since $\mathcal{F}\otimes \tau = \sigma(\{A\times B \: | \: A \in \mathcal{F},B\in \tau\})$). Assuming that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then the Radon-nikodym theorem ensures the existence of $\frac{dQ}{d\nu \otimes \mu_\Theta}$. It clearly follows that
$$\int_A \int_B \frac{dQ}{d\nu\otimes \mu_\Theta} \: d\nu d\mu_\Theta = \int_A\int_B f_{X|\Theta} \: d\nu d\mu_\Theta,$$
for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B\in \tau$. Again we can use that the product sets $A\times B$ generate the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mu_\Theta$, and the two functions must thus be equal $\nu \otimes \mu_\Theta$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 


The part I am confused is the existence of $dQ/(d\nu\times \mu_\theta)$. We cannot extend the special case $C=A\times B$ to all of $C$ immediately. One example is $X=Y=N(0,1)$. If the $\mu_X\times \mu_Y(A\times B)=0$, it implies $Q(A\times B)=0$. ($\mu_X,\mu_Y$ are marginal distributions). 


However, $Q$ (the joint distribution of X,Y) has support on the diagonal, but the diagonal has measure 0 with respect to marginal of $\mu_X\times \mu_Y$. (This example does not contradict the problem, since $\nu$ in this case is not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Zorualyh yes, there was a reason i assumed the measure to be $\sigma$-finite. And your example shows that it is indeed a necessary assumption. There are many theorems from measure theory, that rely on $\sigma$-finite measures, so it is a very common assumption. For instance fubini/tonelli theorem is stated for $\sigma$-finite measures and actually the term "product measure" is only uniquely defined when both measures are $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Zorualyh Also i think from the context of the problem, we should think $\Theta$ as a parameter of the distribution of $X$. Setting $X=\Theta$ is equivalent to saying $X$ is a parameter of the distribution of $X$, which to some degree is correct but also somewhat nonsensical from a statistical point of view.

Comment: Would you mind explain a bit how can we extend from the rectangle cases to the general cases? The part $\forall C\in \mathcal{F}\otimes \tau$, $(\nu\times \mu(C)=0 \Rightarrow Q(C)=0$. I tried to use $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, however these $C$ are not $\lambda$-system. The example $X=Y=N(0,1)$ is kind of saying this extension is not trivial, it has to do something with $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)$. I just have no idea how can $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta}$ show up in the proof

Comment: Let $I = \{A \times B \: | \: A \in \mathcal{F},B \in \tau\}$, and $\mathcal{C}= \{ C \in \mathcal{F} \otimes \tau \: | \: \nu \otimes \mu_\Theta (C) = 0 \Rightarrow Q(C) = 0\}$ and note that $\sigma(I) = \mathcal{F} \otimes \tau$. The goal is to prove $\mathcal{C} = \sigma(I)$ and clearly $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \sigma(I)$. Furthermore since $I \subseteq \mathcal{C}$, it suffices to prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, which it is.

Comment: It is not closed under complement though. Suppose $C$ satisfy the statement. Now consider $C^c$. If $\nu\times \mu(C^c)>0$ then we are done, but if $\nu\times \mu(C^c)=0$, it seems there is no way to prove $Q(C^c)=0$? We can conclude $\nu\times \mu(C)>0$ from this. However this does not help at all..